# How do I script a Load Impact load test to simulate only Chrome users?

Tags: scripting, load-testing, stress-testing

*We’ve come across this question fairly often at Load Impact, so I’m adding it to the Stack Overflow community to make it easier to find*

Q: Different browser behave differently when loading content from a server. Also, some sites/apps deliver different content depending on which browser is being used. How do I make my Load Impact load test emulate a certain browser?

Answer (score 0):

To emulate a specific browser, you can use the load script API functions http.set_user_agent_string() and http.set_max_connections() to configure the simulated client to behave as if it was the browser in question.

#### Here is code where we perform an emulation of IE6

```
-- Emulating IE6
http.set_user_agent_string("Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.1; SV1; .NET CLR 2.0.50727)")
http.set_max_connections(34, 2)
-- make several HTTP requests as IE6
http.request_batch({
  {"GET", "http://test.loadimpact.com/"},
  {"GET", "http://test.loadimpact.com/index.php"},
  {"GET", "http://test.loadimpact.com/news.php"},
  {"GET", "http://test.loadimpact.com/contacts.php"}
})
```

In the above example, we configure the simulated client to do two things:

Use the specific *User-Agent* string used by an Internet Explorer 6 browser running on Windows XP
Use max 2 concurrent connections per target host, and max 34 concurrent connections in total in the first example, [like IE6 would](http://www.browserscope.org/?category=network&v=1&ua=Chrome%2022%2CIE%206)
The result will be that because all the four requests we make are to the same host (“test.loadimpact.com”), 2 connections will be used to fetch 2 things in parallel. If each transaction takes e.g. 100 ms it means the whole batch of requests will have taken a total of 200 ms to complete for IE6.

#### And here is the same code, but instead emulating Chrome 22

```
-- Emulating Chrome 22
http.set_user_agent_string("Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.1 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/22.0.1207.1 Safari/537.1")
http.set_max_connections(17, 6)
-- make several HTTP requests as Chrome 22
http.request_batch({
  {"GET", "http://test.loadimpact.com/"},
  {"GET", "http://test.loadimpact.com/index.php"},
  {"GET", "http://test.loadimpact.com/news.php"},
  {"GET", "http://test.loadimpact.com/contacts.php"}
})
```

Chrome 22 uses up to [6 concurrent connections to the same host, and up to 17 concurrent connections in total](http://www.browserscope.org/?category=network&v=1&ua=Chrome%2022%2CIE%206). In our example that would mean that Chrome was able to open 4 concurrent connections to the “test.loadimpact.com” host and fetch all four items in parallel. If each item takes 100 ms to fetch, it would mean the whole batch of requests were done in just 100 ms.

The *User-Agent* string we set in both examples will be sent in the “User-Agent:” HTTP header to the web server when our simulated client makes a request, making the remote web server believe that the client is using this particular browser/platform combination. For some sites it can trigger delivery of specialized content that has been adapted for a particular browser and/or platform.

Because Chrome uses up to three times as many concurrent connections as IE6 to the same host when it is fetching things, it means it can fetch things much faster (up to three times faster). This also places the target host/system under a lot more pressure, which is why it is important to emulate the right mix of browsers when you run your load test.

To learn more about performance-affecting browser characteristics, [Browserscope](http://www.browserscope.org) is a good source of information.